# Why does Python call both functions?

Tags: python

I have some problems to understand what happens here.

This is my source:

```
class Calc():

    def __init__(self,Ideal,Limit,Value,Debug=None):

        self.Ideal = Ideal
        self.Limit = Limit
        self.Value = Value
        self.Debug = Debug
        self.Grade = self.GetGrade()
        self.LenGrade = self.GetLenGrade()

    def GetGrade(self):
        if self.Debug:
            print('calling GetGrade')
        return Grade

    def GetLenGrade(self):
        if self.Debug:
            print('calling GetLenGrade')
        return Grade
```

When calling it with

```
GradeMinLen += Calc(TargetLen, LimitMinLen, Length ,Debug=1).LenGrade
```

I get always the output

```
calling GetGrade    
calling GetLenGrade
```

Why is python calling `GetGrade`?

Comment: You're calling both functions in `__init__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your object initialisation code, you have the following:

```
self.Grade = self.GetGrade()
self.LenGrade = self.GetLenGrade()
```

This means "set the value of the data member Grade to the value obtained by calling the method GetGrade" and the same for LenGrade.

It should not be surprising that they're called, it would be more surprising if they were not.

Answer (score 2):

You create an instance of `Calc()`, and whenever you do that, `Calc.__init__()` is called for that new instance.

Your `Calc.__init__()` method calls both `self.GetGrade()` and `self.GetLenGrade()`:

```
self.Grade = self.GetGrade()
self.LenGrade = self.GetLenGrade()
```

It doesn't matter here that *after* you created the instance you only access the `LenGrade` attribute; the above two lines in `__init__` do not store method references, they store the *results* of the method calls. The `Calc(...).LenGrade` then returns one of those results; the other result is *also* there however.